# How to maintain different log files for different purposes in Yii2

Tags: php, logging, config, yii2

I am using Yii2 for a project. I have a class for consuming a third party service. This class has two methods sendRequest and processResponse. I would like to maintain separate logs for payload in sendRequest before actually sending it and another log for the raw response data received in processResponse before doing any processing. Additionally I would like log rotation on both logs as the files may grow indefinitely and want both files to be separate from the default app.log. Is this possible? How may I implement this using Yii2 APIs?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I eventually reverted back to using Yii2 logger by adding 2 additional file targets in my @app/config/main.php. The file targets had categories = ['orders'] and ['pushNotifications'] respectively so that in my code I use:

```
Yii::info($message, 'pushNotifications');
```

or

```
Yii::info($message, 'orders');
```

Here is my log config:

```
'log' => [
    'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
    'targets' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
            'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
            'levels' => ['info'],
            'categories' => ['orders'],
            'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/Orders/requests.log',
            'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
            'maxLogFiles' => 20,
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
            'levels' => ['info'],
            'categories' => ['pushNotifications'],
            'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/Orders/notification.log',
            'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
            'maxLogFiles' => 50,
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: I published a refinement of this technique here in the [Zen and the Art of Craft CMS Log File Reading](https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-custom-logger-for-craft-cms#custom-plugin-module-logging-behavior) article

Answer (score 1):

Since I wasn't quite sure how to configure Yii2 logger to do what I wanted, and googling the subject wasn't much help I decided to go with a third-party logger. The one I chose was Monolog. This functionality was only needed in one class so I create a static getLogger method which returned an instance of Monolog\Logger.

```
public static function getLogger($name) {
    $logger = new \Monolog\Logger($name);
    $logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handlers\RotatingFileHandle(Yii::getAlias("@app/runtime/logs/$name.log")), \Monolog\Logger::INFO);
    return $logger;
}
```

Then in sendRequest method I use:

```
static::getLogger('orders')->info($outgoingXmlPayload.$curlResponseXml);
```

In the processResponse method I use:

```
static::getLogger('pushNotifications')->info($notificationXml);
```

I will be glad to hear(or read) from anyone who has a better solution still. Thanks.
--Ab

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk `*` may also come handy if we need to collect more subcategories into a cummulative file:

```
'log' => [
    'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
    'flushInterval' => 100, // may prevent from memory exhaustion
    'targets' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
            'categories' => ['eshop1*'],
            'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/eshop1.log',
            'logVars' => [], // don't log global vars
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
            'categories' => ['eshop2*'],
            'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/eshop2.log',
            'logVars' => ['GET', 'POST'], // log some globals
            'exportInterval' => 100, // may prevent from memory exhaust
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, for dev log

```
  'components' => [
    'log' => [
      'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 10 : 0,
      'targets' => [
        [
          'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
          'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/dev.log',
          'categories' => ['dev'],
          'levels' => ['trace'],
        ],
      ],
    ],
```

it's used

```
Yii::debug('log step 1', 'dev');
```